# Is there any sample code to access the user's Facebook Profile details in iphone sdk?

Tags: objective-c

I want to access my own account user details in facebook like Messages,friend requests,Notifications,my profile pic and my profile details. Is there any sample code or any way to do so??

Anyone's help will be deeply appreciated.

Thanks to all,
Monish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nice introduction to the Facebook SDK, including sample code for iOS:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/